# Extract points which are located along a path which connects two points in coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

Hi I have over 100 data points which are located across a region and 120 station pairs.

I want to extract some of them which are located along a station pair.

Therefore, maybe the code will be needed related to..

1. Find the information of the path from one station to another station in coordinate system.
2. Extract some data points which are near the station pair path in assigned distance.

Could you please let me know whether it is possible or not and the solutions?

Comment: Are Paths straight lines between the coordinates? If that were the case this seems to be equivalent to finding the equation of the line defining an error that is how much deviation from the path you wish to tolerate and use some coordinate geometry (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1530374/729980) to find the distance for each remaining point

Comment: Yeah The all the coordinates are 2D, so the paths are straight line. I see. That can be one of solutions.